# Is it possible have a cell fusion by just injecting human sperm to an unfertilized chicken egg?

Tags: biology, genetics

I stumbled upon these video documentation titled '[Humonculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homunculus)' in Youtube (I know Youtube is not reliable source, but the video to me looks legit and well video documented) by channel named Planet Nibiru. The videos were about a Russian Alchemist 'Kortney' that made an experiment by injecting human sperm to an unfertilized egg. The videos were from another channel/user also in Youtube which is the OP (Как Сделать). The title of one of the [OP's videos](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjgooGVwfHcAhWFad4KHU5zA9wQwqsBMAB6BAgGEAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DHNLPXzlz6-I&usg=AOvVaw0bS_ZykE-LMb93RrWtf2z-) is 'How to make a homunculus'.

From the transcript:

> Today we are going to do an experiment on creating a homunculus.
>    A homunculus is an artificial living creature. The creation of a homunculus is described in the medieval treatises by the scientist Paracelsus.
>
> [...]
>
> For creating a homunculus it is necessary to make a hole in the egg. [...] We have to inject the sperm. [...] The injection should be made exactly into the egg yolk.

The whole documentation runs with like 21 videos until just recently this year since they have not heard any update anymore from Kortney according to comments that the Alchemist was dead by a heart attack (which may also sound suspicious).
These videos shows the trial and error until he was able to reproduce an organism from the egg until it grow and he was able to feed it.

The viewers were divided if it was fake or real, but the organism that moves in the video looks real unless someone has made an effort for good CGI. I would recommend you to watch the whole 21 videos from the Russian OP in youtube than the short video discussion in Planet Nibiru channel to give you the whole point of view.

According to Wikipedia, in order for cell fusion to occur it needs to have enhancer like [PEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyethylene_glycol) or virus.So is it possible to have ['Somatic Fusion'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somatic_fusion) to occur by doing so?

Comment: Last time I saw those videos, they looked really fake to me.

Comment: Yeah, 80% of my brain says fake too, but the movement of the organism just too good to be fake, that's where I get skeptical. lol

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Skeptics SE. The format for Skeptics SE is the following: you bring us a **notable claim** (see the [help center](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [Skeptics Meta SE](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/806/how-notable-does-a-claim-have-to-be-for-questions-about-it-to-be-considered-on-t?noredirect=1&lq=1) for what constitutes a notable claim) and ask "Is this claim true or not?". Users will then answer you "Yes, and here is the evidence", or "No, and here is the evidence" or "Don't know... there does not seem to be any evidence".

Comment: So what is your **notable claim** in this case?

Comment: Even if we ignore the cell fusion part - how should two non-matching chromosome sets lead to a new organism? This is so definitely fake. If it is this organisms movement that made you doubt, I recommend asking on [Movie&TV.SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/tour) how this realistic (?) movement can be generated.

Comment: Those Russian homunculus videos [are definitely fake](https://youtu.be/U5EDORs8Jkk?t=424), and give next to no explanation as to how they work other than 'alchemy' and various conditions that make it difficult for anyone to replicate so we can't exactly test it. Is there any source of this claim other than a single anonymous person and a channel named after [a conspiracy/hoax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibiru_cataclysm)?

Comment: @Giter: Is that not an answer?

Comment: @MichaelK: The title has the claim. The link to the [video with 17 million views](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HNLPXzlz6-I) shows a man injecting semen (?? I don't speak Russian) into a hen's egg and growing a moving embryo (?). If that is what is purported to be happening, that is an extraordinary claim.

Comment: @Oddthinking [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uE-1RPDqJAY) has 27 million views... still does not mean people believe that there are hobbits and that they are being taken to Isengard. If I make a post where the headline "Are the hobbits really being taken to Isengard" and use that video as the source of the claim, the question will get closed for not being a notable claim... since it is about **fiction**. And considering the video in the question has been categorised as "Entertainment" by the uploader — just like the Hobbits video — I still doubt that this is a notable claim.

Comment: @Oddthinking: It's not really an answer as much as it is a "that's a bad source, you should find a better one". The question is basically "can somatic fusion occur with human sperm and a chicken egg", but I have no idea if that's what is actually being claimed in the videos since I don't speak Russian. Also, the guy making the videos doesn't seem to use his real name so we can't look up if he's a VFX artist that's just doing it for fun/practice/money.

Comment: @MichaelK: Giter's linked video does an analysis of the comments and media responses on the homonculus video to show people believe it. (I feel you are setting the bar too high for what is notable enough for the site. We should take this to meta if we are still disagreeing.)

Comment: @Giter: The lack of an English translation to the claim is holding us back; I am tempted to put it on hold until we can get a clearer claim.

Comment: @MichaelK I think the notable **claim** here is that, by just injecting a semen to an unfertilized egg, through trial and error (if you'll check the video he injected more than a dozen and incubated it from 10 - 40 days), he was able to reproduced a somewhat  deformed moving organism, and you could hear him saying _probably_ not Genetic hybrid but could be _Somatic fusion_, in one of his video. Also, it was mentioned in the video of other channel I mentioned **Nibiru Planet** that Alchemy or creation of Humonculus already existed since at the age of BC and was already practiced the same steps.

Comment: Yes, sorry to confuse anyone, there is a caption in the video. I don't really understand russian, but I read the caption while watching it.

Comment: Here is the chat room: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81773/regarding-the-russian-humonculus-video

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is nothing to indicate that this video is meant to be taken seriously or that people do take it seriously.